# Store Dagger component in a static field

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I´m new in Dagger2 and most of the time I´ve seen people creating the **AppComponent** in an extended **Application** Class. So any time you need the AppComponent you´ll request it through the Application class.

```
public class App extends Application {

private AppComponent mAppComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); 
    mAppComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
            .build();
}

public AppComponent getAppComponent() {
    return mAppComponent;
}

@VisibleForTesting
public void setAppComponent(AppComponent appComponent) {
    mAppComponent = appComponent;
}
}
```

I´ve also seen people using a **ComponentFactory**

```
public class ComponentFactory {

public static final AppComponent getComponent(Application context) {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(context))
                .build();
    }
```

Which are the pros and cons about storing the AppComponent in the Application class?

is it better to create it through the Factory each time we need it?

Will it be any problem if we keep in a static field a Component instead of building it each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building your component each time can be (depending on the size of your component) wasteful, but more importantly, any `@Scope` annotations you use will not share the same instance if you recreate your component each time. Storing your component in your `Application` class is a common approach as it provides a canonical place to retrieve the component across your app. A `static` field can be tricky when you consider the lifecycle of your app (especially with testing) and is generally considered to be an anti-pattern. You get a lot of the same benefits by keeping your component in your application class since you can correctly assume that the Android framework will only create one `Application` instance as long as your app is alive. If there's only one `Application` and it only creates one component, you ensure singularity and you can properly control visibility to the component.